# Informatica pre sql to drop an index

Tags: sql, plsql

I am trying to load 2 million records into a oracle table using the Oracle external loader in Informatica. In order to load the data, I am trying to drop the index on the table and re create after the data is loaded. I am using the below anonymous block in the pre SQL in mapping for the target:

```
Declare indxcnt int\;

 BEGIN

  SELECT COUNT(INDEX_NAME) 
  INTO indxcnt 
  FROM all_INDEXES WHERE INDEX_NAME  = 'TEST_INDEX1'\;

  IF indxcnt > 0 THEN
     Execute Immediate 'DROP INDEX TEST_INDEX1'\;
  END If \;
 END\;
```

However the pre SQL is not working and as the index is not getting dropped.

When I use the same anonymous block in the session properties using the relation writer, it is working fine.

Kindly help me how to drop and re create the index while using the loader to load the table.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the software you want to execute. You can do it by /:

This is in PL/SQL. I don't know informatica but perhaps this could help you.

```
DECLARE 
  indxcnt NUMBER;
BEGIN
  --
  SELECT COUNT(INDEX_NAME) 
  INTO indxcnt 
  FROM all_indexes WHERE index_name = 'TEST_INDEX1';
  --
  IF indxcnt > 0 
  THEN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP INDEX TEST_INDEX1';
  END IF;
END;
/
```